# how to allow/read percentage sign in url htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am using htaccess rule for url rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+)&year=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

this makes url like

```
 www.example.com/buy-car/audi/x5/2015
```

but sometime i may have url like this

```
www.example.com/buy-car/audi/x5/2000%3B2015

%3B represents ;
```

now how to change my htaccess rules to work fine.

thanks

Comment: Did you try using '%25' instead of liteal '%'? Also, there is plenty of related information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673439/error-with-and-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash in front of %. Try using: ([\%\w-]+) in your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Allow `;` in your character class. Have 2nd rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w;-]+)/([\w;-]+)/([\w;-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```